# Azure Synapse Link for Dataverse - Tables from F&O - only available via Spark pool for Delta Lake?

Tags: azure-synapse, dataverse, azure-synapse-analytics

I am migrating a project from one tenant to another, which in essence is ETL job from Dynamics 365 F&O to Power BI Reporting.

I am using Azure Synapse Link for Dataverse to fetch data from Dynamics, which will be plugged into migrated pipelines in Azure Synapse, which will take care of the rest.

This is one of the few deviations from original project, which used older version (Export to Data Lake in finance and operations), deprecated by Microsoft, where referenced were specific tables in F&O.

Problem I have is substantial, with solution nowhere to be found in the internet: I seem to be unable to replicate that granularity - when setting up the link in Power Apps panel all I get is this:
[image]

But for my purpose I need this:
[image]

For now the only way to get to picture 2 is to set up ASLD to use Spark pool:
[image]

Is it truly the case? Is there no other way to be able to query tables from F&O, and not Dataverse entities?

That would mean extra cost of the Spark pool, which - as per Microsoft warnings about overhead of ASLD - may need more than one standard node and for much more time than with non-Spark link...

And since I have not much experience with Spark in Azure Synapse Analytics, I am not sure how difficult it will be to swap sources for the whole migrated solution. Any tips, please?